# Which one has the same meaning?

Tags: paraphrasing

It was quite clear that this place was not big enough to house all the family members.

-between the two sentences below,
Which one has the same meaning as the one above?

It was quite cleat that this place was not so big that it could house all the family members

It was quite clear that this place was not so big that it couldn't house all the family members

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming "It was quite cleat" is a typo, and should be "It was quite clear".
The first of your two sentences has the same meaning as your first statement.
The second uses a "double negative; - "not" and "couldn't" which effectively, cancel each other out. The second sentence actually means, that it could house all the family members.

[**Double negative**](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiut-P09LbbAhVGEpQKHbrlAXYQFgg5MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbandictionary.com%2Fdefine.php%3Fterm%3Ddouble%2520negative&usg=AOvVaw2RxD6jmapcjXnh3W7bpzEH):

> The use of two negatives, which cancel each other out.
>
> "a syntactic construction in which two negative words are used in the same clause to express a single negation."
>
> "He didn't say nothing" MEANS- He said something.
> "I ain't not never gunna do it" MEANS- I will do it.
> "There is not nobody who will go" MEANS- Someone will go.
> "I don't want nothing" MEANS- I want something.
> "We don't need no education" MEANS- We need education.
>
> If a man did not say nothing, that means he said something.

Comment: I think it is important to mention that often, a double negative _does_ actually have a negative meaning. _You ain't seen nothing yet_ doesn't normally mean _you've seen something_.  Also, your second example (I ain't not never gunna do it) is a _triple_ negative, so should logically mean _I will not do it_.

Comment: The above examples are a quote from the Urban dictionary. I wish I could edit it because the triple example "I ain't not never" =  I am not not never!  Many songs with double negatives (such as "You ain't seen nothing yet")

Comment: Whoops!  I got stuck in edit mode, and didn't realise I only had 5 minutes to complete it.  I wanted to delete the above post from "Many songs.."  Also wanted to say "Thanks oerkelens"  Thanks oerkelens.

Answer (score 0):

From a logical point of view, two negative cancel each other out, and produce a positive meaning. This is not how language works all the time, though.

Pedants will point out what they see as a flaw in logic when you tell them *I didn't see nothing*: it can be parsed as *I saw something*. In real life, however, that utterance will more often be interpreted (and intended!) to mean *I din't see anything*.

So when *does* a double negative work? It depends on context and semantics.
If I look at one of @RobynSimpson's examples, the context is very important:

> We don't need no education
>   We don't need no thought control
>   No dark sarcasm in the classroom
>   Teachers leave them kids alone
>   Hey! Teachers! Leave them kids alone

These lines are from Pink Floyd's *Another brick in the wall*.

The two first lines both contain a double negative, but their meaning is not positive. The context makes it quite clear that those lines do *not* mean "we need education, and we need though control".

So, did Pink Floyd mess up their language or grammar?

No, this construction is incredibly common (the Rolling Stones sang *I can't get no satisfaction*) and in everyday use, *I didn't do nothing* is often considered acceptable in non-formal registers.

Now, let's have a look at your second option:

> It was quite clear that this place was not so big that it couldn't house all the family members.

Clearly, your first option is logically and grammatically the one that conveys the same meaning as your original sentence, but your second option can be read as having the same meaning!

I do admit the sentence is a bit confusing, and I would advise against using it like this. However, I have come across sentences like this in real life, and parsed them as having a negative meaning based on semantics.

Why would I say the house was not *so* big - basically saying it *was* big - but not to the extend that it could *not* house the whole family? That is a non-sequitur, leading me to believe the second negation is only there for emphasis, meaning that indeed, the two negatives are not cancelling each other out.

A semantically different statement would lead me to believe the two negative *are* meant to form a positive:

> It was quite clear that this place was not so *small* that it couldn't house all the family members.

In this case I would certainly parse the sentence to mean that the house is big enough for a whole family.